# Laravel 5.1 links with url() function only to http

Tags: php, http, laravel, url, https

When I try to get the link of my site (for example domain.com), I just do `url();` and it returns me `http://www.domain.com`. but what if I want to get a secure url (https) in my production and to get unsecured (http) in my local?

I don't want to use `secure_url()` and `secure_asset()` functions because I'm working on localhost too.

**Update**

Is there any trick I can do if I'm using cloudflare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to add CloudFlare's ips in the `Request::setTrustedProxies()` method, It worked for me, I don't really know why but it fixed the problem..

Thank you all for helping! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
url('foo/bar', [], app()->environment() !== 'local');
```

This'll produce a secure `URL` if the environment is not `local` so make sure you set local environment for development and production environment for live server.

Also, you may use `app()->environment() == 'production'` instead so only when environment is set to `production` then it'll produce a secure `URL` otherwise a non-secure `URL` will be generated.

Also, you may use something like these:

```
url('foo/bar', [], !app()->environment('local')); // if not local
url('foo/bar', [], app()->environment('production')); // if production
url('foo/bar', [], !app()->environment('local', 'staging')); // if not local/staging
```

*Note: Don't forget to [set the environment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration) to `local/production` in `env` file.*

Comment: But I used this function for like 100+ times.. Doing it to every time I did is a real pain.. I'm using cloudflare, Is there any trick it can do?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question in the comment :(

Comment: Using this method every time is really big pain, but I fixed it by adding cloudflare's ips in `Request::setTrustedProxies()` method

Answer (score 1):

Did you really try using url on both production and local development?

When you do `url('foo/bar');` it checks whether your request is secure or not.

So if you access your website through http, all your urls will be http, if you access through https all your generated links will be over https.

This is the UrlGenerator

```
/**
 * Get the scheme for a raw URL.
 *
 * @param  bool|null  $secure
 * @return string
 */
protected function getScheme($secure)
{
    if (is_null($secure)) {
        if (is_null($this->cachedSchema)) {
            $this->cachedSchema = $this->forceSchema ?: $this->request->getScheme().'://';
        }

        return $this->cachedSchema;
    }

    return $secure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
}
```

Which will call this:

```
 /**
 * Checks whether the request is secure or not.
 *
 * This method can read the client protocol from the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header
 * when trusted proxies were set via "setTrustedProxies()".
 *
 * The "X-Forwarded-Proto" header must contain the protocol: "https" or "http".
 *
 * If your reverse proxy uses a different header name than "X-Forwarded-Proto"
 * ("SSL_HTTPS" for instance), configure it via "setTrustedHeaderName()" with
 * the "client-proto" key.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isSecure()
{
    if ($this->isFromTrustedProxy() && self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO] && $proto = $this->headers->get(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO])) {
        return in_array(strtolower(current(explode(',', $proto))), array('https', 'on', 'ssl', '1'));
    }

    $https = $this->server->get('HTTPS');

    return !empty($https) && 'off' !== strtolower($https);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. I'm using cloudflare's ssl. does it mean something to laravel?

Comment: @EliyaCohen Cloudflare has its own rewrite rules so if you enable SSL on Cloudflare, your Laravel app is not aware of the secure url being used for this function to work properly. If you used SSL through web server configuration, it will properly pick up on this logic.